# Приклади мови Галичини початку ХХст

Tags: resource-request, історія-мови, діалекти

Я шукаю приклади текстів розмовною українською мовою Галичини періоду 1890-1918рр.
Чи є десь у вільному онлайн-доступі відскановані газети що видавались Львові на початку ХХст?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я не знаю, наскільки це стосується розмовної української, але відскановані газети/журнали/книги є.

(Я неодноразово натрапляв на різні матеріали під час користування пошуком, але більшість, на жаль, не пам'ятаю. Буду, можливо, поступово доповнювати цей перелік, якщо на щось натраплю знову. Закликаю інших робити те саме — це wiki-відповідь.)

Отже, **матеріали, видані у Львові наприкінці XIX — на початку XX ст.**:

- [«Діло»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)#%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8) (стаття містить посилання на архівні номери)
- [«Житє і слово»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Zhytie_i_slovo/)
- [«Записки» й інші матеріали Наукового товариства імені Шевченка](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Naukove_tovarystvo_imeni_Shevchenka/) (значною мірою видавалися у Львові, але не лише там)
- [«Зоря»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Zoria/)
- [«Літературно-науковий вістник»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) (значною мірою видавався у Львові, але не лише там;  стаття містить посилання на архівні номери)
- [«Правда (письмо літературно політичне)»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Pravda_Pysmo_literaturno-politychne/)

Також певною мірою можуть бути корисними такі сайти й сторінки, бо вони згадують, посилаються на або ж безпосередньо містять, зокрема, й потрібні Вам матеріали (зазначу, що статті у Вікіпедії, присвячені певним видавцям/виданням, іноді містять посилання на архівні номери):

- [chtyvo.org.ua](http://chtyvo.org.ua/genre/chasopysy/books/)
- [diasporiana.org.ua](http://diasporiana.org.ua/)
- [libraria.ua](https://libraria.ua/)
- [zbruc.eu](https://zbruc.eu/125_years_ago)
- категорія [«Львівські історичні періодичні видання»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) в Українській Вікіпедії
- категорія [«Часописи Львова»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8_%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) в Українській Вікіпедії
- стаття-перелік [«Українські часописи Львова до 1939 року»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8_%D0%9B%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE_1939_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) в Українській Вікіпедії

Comment: Найціннішими для вивчення розмовної мови, на мою думку, є оголошення, жарти та смішні історії. Zbruc.eu має переважно публіцистику і серйозні статті з газети "Діло", а ще по ньому не зрозуміло чи стаття не редагувалась при розпізнаванні. Libraria.ua дає повні газети, але вже періоду Польщі, а не Австро-Угорщини. "Записки НТШ" та "Житє і слово" майже повністю література і можливо там автори, як і Франко, намагалися наблизити мову до мови центальної України.

Comment: @Volodymyr, чесно кажучи, поки не маю ідей. Можна спробувати пошукати гумористичні журнали (наприклад, http://diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/671/file.pdf — але це Аргентина, 1952 і не факт, що редактори там не намагатися звести до певного стилю).